# Does anyone know the omega-limit set of this system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By any chance, does someone know the Omega-limit set of the solution of the following system with the initial condition $x(0)=10$ and $y(0)=0$:

$$x'=1-x+y^3$$
$$y'=y(1-x+y)$$

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a polar coordinates transformation ?

Comment: yes I tried, but it did not yield to something useful!

Comment: For finding the omega limit set, should I find the solutions of this system first, or there is another way to find that?

Comment: No, the whole point of such analysis is making claims for the solutions without explicitly having them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one seems to be pretty straightforward in cartesian coordinates; we are given the system

$\dot x = 1 - x + y^3, \tag 1$

$\dot y = y(1 - x + y); \tag 2$

the critical points occur where $\dot x = \dot y = 0$, that is, where

$1 - x + y^3 = 0, \tag 3$

$y(1 - x + y) = 0; \tag 4$

solutions:  $x = 1$, $y = 0$; that's it for $y = 0$, which forces $x = 1$; if $y \ne 0$, then

$1 - x + y = 0, \tag 5$

$y = x - 1; \tag 6$

we substitute this into (3):

$1 - x + (x - 1)^3 = 0, \tag 7$

$(1 - x)(1 - (1 - x)^2) = 0, \tag 8$

$x = 1, \tag 9$

or

$x^2 - 2x + 1 = (x - 1)^2 = 1; \tag{10}$

$x^2 - 2x = 0 \Longrightarrow x = 0, \; x = 2; \tag{11}$

from (6), the critical points are $(0, -1)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(2, 1)$; we see there is exactly one on the $x$-axis, $(1, 0)$.

We can now solve the problem pitched directly by observing that the $x$-axis is invariant under the flow of (1)-(2); e.g., when $y = 0$, (1)-(2) become

$\dot x = 1 - x, \tag{12}$

$\dot y = 0; \tag{13}$

to be more specific, we observe that (12) implies

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(-\ln(1 - x)) = \left ( \dfrac{\dot x}{1 - x} \right ) = 1, \tag{14}$

which integrated with respect to $t$ yields

$-\ln(1 - x(t)) + \ln (1 - x(t_0)) = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \dfrac{d}{ds}(-\ln(1 - x(s))) \;ds$
$=  \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \left ( \dfrac{\dot x(s)}{1 - x(s)}\right ) \; ds = \int_{t_0}^t 1 \; ds = t - t_0; \tag{15}$

$\ln \left (\dfrac{1 - x(t_0)}{1 - x(t)} \right ) = t - t_0, \tag{16}$

$\dfrac{1 - x(t_0)}{1 - x(t)} = e^{t - t_0}, \tag{17}$

$1 - x(t) = (1 - x(t_0))e^{t_0 - t}, \tag{18}$

$x(t) = 1 - (1 - x(t_0))e^{t_0 - t}. \tag{19}$

It is now a simple matter the verify that

$(x(t), y(t)) = (1 - (1 - x(t_0))e^{t_0 - t}, 0) \tag{20}$

is the integral curve of (1)-(2) which passes through the point $(x(t_0), 0)$ at $t = t_0$; if we take $t_0 = 0$, $x(t_0) = 10$ then this becomes

$(x(t), y(t)) = (1 +9e^{t_0 - t}, 0) \tag{21}$

from this it follows that

$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} (x(t), y(t)) = (1, 0), \tag{22}$

that is, the $\omega$-limit set of this solution is $(1, 0)$.

The reader will note that it is not really necessary to find the exact solution to determine the $\omega$-limit set; once we have (12)-(13), that this set consists solely of the point $(1, 0)$ is readily inferred.

Comment: Thankyou very much Robert. It was really helpful.

Comment: @Derby:  you are most welcome my friend!  If you really found this helpful, you might consider the green checmark!  Cheers! 

Comment: @Derby:  muchas gracias, mi amogo! 

Comment: de nada, Robert :)

Comment: @Derby:  I'm posting some edits in a few minutes!  Stay tuned!

Comment: @Derby:  it may take more than a few, but it's coming!